# How to generate QR code in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, qr-code

How to Generate QR Code from iPhone with Password protection?. I should generate QR code for given Image with Password protection. When read it from iPhone

Comment: Use [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)'s iPhone module.

Comment: What do you mean by password protection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this framework : [onbarcode](http://www.onbarcode.com/products/iphone_barcode/barcodes/qrcode.html) or [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)

Answer (score 21):

Now with iOS 7 it can be done directly without additional libraries. There's an excellent example at https://github.com/shu223/iOS7-Sampler

Answer (score 7):

I have found one very simple way how to generate QR Code using Google Api.Just take 1 UIWebView in your code I have taken IBOutlet UIWebView *webView; and I want add this Much of Information in My QR Code.
1.Business Name
2.First Name and  Last Name
3.Physical Address and phone
4.Website

```
NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=200x200&chl=MECARD:ORG%@CN%@%@CTEL%@CADR%@%@%@%@%@CEMAIL%@",[d valueForKey:@"QR Business Name"],[d valueForKey:@"QR First Name"],[d valueForKey:@"QR Last Name"],[d valueForKey:@"QR Phone"],[d valueForKey:@"QR Physical Address"],[d valueForKey:@"QR Physical City"],[d valueForKey:@"QR Physical State"],[d valueForKey:@"QR Physical Zip"],[d valueForKey:@"QR Physical Zip Plus 4"],[d valueForKey:@"QR Website"]];

url=[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *Curl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:Curl];
//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try https://github.com/myang-git/QR-Code-Encoder-for-Objective-C. Recently I added the ability to encrypt/decrypt by AES